# gganimate object 'frame_time' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have a map that I am animating using the package `gganimate`.

Each frame is equal to one day and I am trying to set the title of the animation to be the date using `labs(title = 'Date: {frame_time}')`. However, the animation does not display and I get several warnings saying `object 'frame_time' not found`.

I have noticed that when I run the code with `transition_time(date)` I do not get the warnings. However, the rendering time increases by an order of magnitude (i.e., what takes 5 seconds to render suddenly takes 5+ minutes to render).

How can I set the title to be the date and use `transition_manual(date)`?

Example Data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(geodata)
library(sf)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

# Get outline of Texas

tx <- gadm(country = 'USA', level = 1, path=tempdir()) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 %in% 'Texas') %>%
  mutate(State = NAME_1) %>%
  select(State, geometry)

# Fake data to use for map

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df1)[1:4] <- c('State','date_start','date_end','event')
df1$State <- 'Texas'
df1$date_start <- c(as.Date('2020-01-02'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-10'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-16'))
df1$date_end <- c(as.Date('2020-01-05'),
                  as.Date('2020-01-13'),
                  as.Date('2020-01-24'))
df1$event <- c('moderate','strong','severe')

df1 <- left_join(df1,tx, by = 'State')

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 31))
colnames(df2)[1] <- 'date'
df2$date <- seq.Date(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                     as.Date('2020-01-31'),
                     1)

datt <- left_join(df2, df1, by = join_by(between(date, date_start, date_end))) %>%
  select(date,event,geometry) %>%
  mutate(geometry = tx$geometry,
         event = ifelse(is.na(event),'None',event)) %>%
  mutate(event = case_match(event,
                            'None' ~ 'None',
                            'moderate' ~ 'Moderate',
                            'strong' ~ 'Strong',
                            'severe' ~ 'Severe'))

cols <- c('None' = 'white',
          'Moderate' = '#ffda68',
          'Strong' = '#f26722',
          'Severe' = '#cb3827')

# This map takes 5 seconds to render without date as title

map1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = datt,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry,
                        fill = event)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-107.5, -92), ylim = c(25.5, 37), expand = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(fill = 'Severity Classification') +
  theme_void() +
  transition_manual(date)

animate(map1, nframes = 31, fps = 5)

# Map will not display and several warnings when adding: title = 'Date: {frame_time}'

map2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = datt,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry,
                        fill = event)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-107.5, -92), ylim = c(25.5, 37), expand = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(fill = 'Severity Classification',
       title = 'Date: {frame_time}') +
  theme_void() +
  transition_manual(date)

animate(map2, nframes = 31, fps = 5)

# Map take 5+ minutes to render when: title = 'Date: {frame_time}' AND transition_time(date)

map3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = datt,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry,
                        fill = event)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-107.5, -92), ylim = c(25.5, 37), expand = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(fill = 'Severity Classification',
       title = 'Date: {frame_time}') +
  theme_void() +
  transition_time(date)

animate(map3, nframes = 31, fps = 5)
```

Comment: See the help. `transition_time()` creates the `frame_time` variable, `transition_manual()` does not. It makes available `previous_frame`, `current_frame`, and `next_frame`. Does `title = 'Date: {current_frame}')` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! ```current_frame``` did the trick!